# reversible short cryptographic sequence

Tags: algorithm, security, authentication

I want to create a human-readable short and unique sequence from a string that can be reversed (allows getting string from sequence).

the goal is to be able to authenticate a user just by a sequence received by postmail.

I'm thinking about encrypting the source string ("userId+timestamp"), using a symetric key that only the server has. to be able to get back the source string. But I would like to get only a short 8 characters alphanumerical string (base36)such as "QCF9TF4S" instead of a very long cipher text,

is this even possible ?

Comment: 8 * log_2(36) ~= 41 bits. That means there is a higher than negligible chance that a hacker simply guesses right. You could just store a random sequence when creating the "postmail" and then map that to a specific user account by keeping a table; that way you'd at least minimize the target (users that require authentication at that particular time). By the way, this is not a programming question, these kind of things are better asked at [security.se].

Comment: While 41 bits is small for cryptographic purposes, I don't see a problem with a 2-trillion value space as long as guessing is reasonably expensive, and the space is sparse enough (human-chosen passwords only have about that much entropy; this isn't a perfect comparison since an account only has one password and there are many valid tokens, but it helps estimate orders of magnitude). The problem with your approach is compression. Your input is likely substantially larger than your output. Encryption can't solve that. How long are userids and how many bytes do you want for the timestamp?

Comment: @RobNapier There is no space for an IV (replay attacks) nor for an authentication tag. So the chance that a random ciphertext hits a valid user ID + timestamp seems larger than 1 in 2-trillion, which is why randomizing and limiting the validity of the unique string seems a good approach to me (used over TLS, preferably, of course).